# How to establish a secure page transfer using a form?

Tags: security, encryption, pci-compliance

I have `index.php` and I have a login form:

```
<form method=post action="login.php" id="login">
 <input type="text" size="16" maxlength="30" name="login" id="login_user" />
 <input type="password" name="pass" id="login_pass"/>
 <input name="msubmit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

How can I make sure that the form gets processed through a secure line?

Do I have to add `https://`?

```
<form method=post action="https://test.com/login.php" id="login"
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to make sure that the form is displayed on a page served through **https** as well, not just pointing to it. Otherwise data will be sent in plain **http**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the best way is to specify `https`:

```
<form method="post" action="https://domain.com/login.php" id="login">
    <input type="text" size="16" maxlength="30" name="login" id="login_user" />
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="login_pass" />
    <input name="msubmit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Even if `index.php` was served through a secure channel, it is good practice to explicitly specify `https` on the post action because this is the request which sends sensitive data over the wire. But it is also recommended to have `index.php` served through `https` only.

Comment: assuming you have brought and set up a ssl certificate.

Comment: @Patrioticcow - Also, each downloaded element (script, stylesheet, image, etc) that is part of the page needs to use `https`.

Comment: i bought a ssl certificate, and my `index.php` is not served through a secure channel.

Comment: @Patrioticcow, it should be. It's really the best practice in terms of security.

Answer (score 0):

Use https protocol. Also treat all the parameters as `tainted` - and get the PHP script to process them in a responsible fashion.

*I.e. parse (regular expressions) them and escape them if necessary when using a database/command line *